# IE7,8 calling all the wrong functions?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, animation

Okay, so I'm trying to do some animation. [Here](http://adamhaskell.net/hatch/) is the test page.

There's a fair quantity of code and I think it's all relevant, so pasting it here might not be worthwhile. I can post the function definitions:

```
var ImageLoader = function(c,imagelist,oncomplete) {
    var l = 0, imgs = [], i, loaded = 0;
    for( i in imagelist) {
        l++;
        imgs[i] = new Image();
        imgs[i].style.position = "absolute";
        imgs[i].style.left = "100%";
        c.appendChild(imgs[i]);
        imgs[i].onload = function() {
            loaded++;
            if( loaded == l) oncomplete(imgs);
        };
        imgs[i].onerror = function() {
            alert("Failed to load "+this.src);
        };
        imgs[i].src = imagelist[i];
    }
};
var img2bg = function(c,img) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.style.width = img.width+"px";
    d.style.height = img.height+"px";
    d.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+img.src+"')";
    d.style.position = "absolute";
    d.style.left = "100%";
    c.appendChild(d);
    return d;
};
var Animate = function(callback,time,thenwhat) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
        var now = new Date().getTime();
        var pos = Math.min(1,(now-start)/time);
        if( callback) callback(pos);
        if( pos == 1) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            if( thenwhat) thenwhat();
        }
    },25);
};
```

However, as I mentioned, this probably isn't very useful on its own.

Anyway, on to the point, this animation works perfectly in IE9, IE10, Chrome, Firefox... But in IE8 and 7 it fails miserably.

In the callback function for `ImageLoader`, I call `img2bg` on two specific images. But for some reason the function is getting called twice for one of the images, and four or five times with no second argument at all. There is literally no other call to `img2bg` in the entire script, so what gives?

Comment: The weirdest part is that even though errors are coming up, the script is not dying. Every other time I've had an error it kills the entire script block, whereas here it only seems to exit the current function...

Comment: In IE 8, I get JS error `Message: 'width' is null or not an object. Line: 30`

Comment: @MuthuKumaran Exactly. [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ycWGC/) so you can add some debugging. Those errors are coming from the calls to `img2bg` that have no second argument.

Comment: Split the `for(i in imagelist) {} ` into two parts: one to compute the final value of `l`, one to do the rest. IE fires the `onload` event as soon as it can, even if the `for` loop is not finished.

Comment: @DCoder: Why does it matter whether the `for` loop is finished?

Comment: @minitech: because the onload handler checks if the number of loaded images is equal to the number of expected images, and calls the "all images loaded!" callback if that is the case. However, due to the way `l` is calculated, it is possible for "the number of expected images" to not be equal to the real size of `imagelist` when this check happens, so the success callback gets called multiple times instead of just once.

Comment: @DCoder: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that it wasn't `imagelist.length` like a normal person would do ;) Kolink: Try that?

Comment: @minitech But it's an associative array, key to url. Objects have no `length` property ;)

Comment: Sorry to mention it yet again, but I'm just wondering if my suggestion helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" to the problem is to feature-detect and make the animation optional so that old browsers can just skip past it or play a simpler one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure all the features you are trying to use work in IE7/8? You use opacity which does not. I know background-position was buggy at best. You use the html5 doctype so I don't know if that means you might be using html5 elements or APIs, too. This is what makes me think the problems lie there.

Comment: The code isn't even getting that for before dying. Besides, setting properties on an object never hurt, even if they don't correspond to recognised styles. I would at least expect the image to appear.

Comment: Then I wouldn't be surprised if it was the javascript alone. IE has never been up to snuff. We used to call it the Miracle Browser. If it worked, it must be a Miracle!

Comment: Yeah... I've been using it for over a decade and this is actually the first real issue I've had with it.

Comment: @Kolink - I'm shocked. We have issues with it daily. Sometimes hourly. We have one whole person who does nothing but deal with it.

Comment: My principle has always been "If it works in IE without hax, it'll work in any other browser". Lately, however, it's been the opposite... Both Chrome and Firefox have been giving me a headache. Example: box-shadow + border-radius in Chrome = square shadow???

Comment: @Kolink - Never, ever do that. It's like working with a broken calculator to get an answer and trying to get the same answer on a good one. Always, always use a modern browser. ANYTHING but IE. Then look to see how badly IE screws things up. But at least you'll know your code is right in the first place. Never, ever trust IE to do anything right. Inept at best, it's the worst browser on the planet by far.

Comment: @Kolink - You sound like you need to read these: http://html5test.com - http://css3test.com - http://caniuse.com - http://people.mozilla.com/~prouget/ie9/

Comment: I did. Most of those unsupported features are either only good for eye-candy, usability nightmares anyway, or things I'd never use in a million years. Just sayin'. Anyways, any chance we could get back to the point here? Why is my function being called without apparent cause?

Comment: @Kolink: did you try my suggestion about splitting the loop? It doesn't make images visible (I suspect that's where opacity or other visual limitations interfere), but it does get all the images loaded without errors.